# How to convert PDF to PDF/A in Erlang?

Tags: pdf, erlang

I'm looking for a **PDF** to [**PDF/A(-3)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDF/A) converter for Erlang.

So far I have not been able to find any solutions to this in Erlang. 
Does anyone know of a good function or module we could use in order to achieve this?

Comment: You are looking for a PDF to PDF/A converter written in Erlang? If not, what languages/binaries are you able to use?

Comment: I'm looking for the solution written in Erlang. Javascript is possible, but not desirable.

Comment: Converting existing file from PDF to PDF/A is non-trivial. There are few options on the market, and if Erlang and JS are your options, then you are very limited indeed. I'm not aware of any FOSS solutions that satisfy your requirements. If you are open to commercial/paid solutions let me know and I can assist further.